# Mocking a singleton class in laravel 5.8 in my phpunit tests

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit, singleton, laravel-5.8

I was trying to mock a singleton class which being injected as dependency into another class. For obvious reasons (the singleton happened before the mocking, at service container level / AppServiceProvider level) the class is a regular instance  instead of a mock object.

The class constructor look like this:

```
    /**
     * constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->classToBeMocked = resolve('ClassToBeMocked');
    }
```

I had to change it to

```
   /**
     * constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(ClassToBeMocked $classToBeMocked)
    {
        $this->classToBeMocked = $classTobeMocked;
    }
```

And stop using the singleton.

Any insights on how to mock a singleton in laravel or a way to re instantiate a singleton so It takes effect once is mocked in the tests.

Thanks

Comment: The example code you have is excactly the same, usually you mock everything up and call the api in the tests and first there it will be instantiated, can i see how you invoke your app?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would define a singleton in a service provider as:

```
$this->app->singleton('ClassToBeMocked');
```

If you are doing this then you can mock it in tests by swapping its instance in the test setup:

```
 protected function setUp():void {
    parent::setUp();
    $mockInstance = $this->getMockBuilder('ClassToBeMocked')->getMock();
    // Define behaviour
    $this->app->instance('ClassToBeMocked', $mockInstance);
 }
```

This way when your dependency injection container tries to resolve the singleton in will instead grab the mock instance. This will work with both `resolve('ClassToBeMocked')` as well as `resolve('ClassWhichTakesClassToBeMockedAsAConstructorArgument')`

Comment: Looks logic but a bit limited from the mock POV. I would have to define a fixed behavior for the entire test class.

Comment: You can move this setup in individual test functions instead (if that's what you mean)

Comment: Yeah, but what I mean is that would be nice if something like: $this->app->re-instance(Class) so would be possible to set different mock behavior within the same test class rather than having to create a new test class per mock behavior

Comment: Each test is run independently so if you do `$this->app->instance('ClassToMock', $mock)` in the test case function itself it should work